# wp_get_attachment_image_src returning different values in local and online page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use custom crop sizes in my web page, how ever the method wp_get_attachment_image_src is returning differetn values in my local page and my web page and I don't know why is happening...

```
print_r(wp_get_attachment_image_src($retrato['id']));
Array ( [0] => https://i1.wp.com/academiadecine.ec/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/no-profile-picture_3.png?resize=150%2C150&ssl=1 
[1] => 150 
[2] => 150 
[3] => 1 )

print_r(wp_get_attachment_image_src($retrato['id'],'sqr_crop'));
Array ( [0] => https://i1.wp.com/academiadecine.ec/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/no-profile-picture_3.png?resize=500%2C500&ssl=1 
[1] => 500 
[2] => 500 
[3] => 1 )
 
In the local page: 
print_r(wp_get_attachment_image_src($retrato['id']));
Array ( [0] => http://academiacineecuatoriana.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/no-profile-picture_3-150x150.png 
[1] => 150 
[2] => 150 
[3] => 1 )
 
print_r(wp_get_attachment_image_src($retrato['id'],'sqr_crop'));
Array ( [0] => http://academiacineecuatoriana.local/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/no-profile-picture_3-500x500.png 
[1] => 500 
[2] => 500 
[3] => 1 )
```

I'm using bluehost as my web host

Comment: `i1.wp.com` is used as an image CDN here by the looks of it. For example the JetPack plugin suite makes use of this, https://wordpress.org/support/topic/what-is-https-i1-wp-com-ss1/

Comment: oh, I just read your comment, thanks that worked!!!